# Getting dimension error when plotting graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to plot a quadratic graph on python. But I'm running into some issues.
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_x_squared():
    new_list = []
    x_values = range(-5,6)
    lista = list(x_values)
    for number in lista:
        new_number = number**2
        new_list.append(new_number)
    return new_list

def get_quadratic_function():
    y_values = get_x_squared
    x = list(range(-5,6))
    y = y_values
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel("x-axis")
    plt.ylabel("y-axis")
    plt.title("Quadratic function")
    plt.show()

print(get_quadratic_function())
```

So the first function `get_x_squared`, gives me the y values squared from -5 to 5. And the second function plots it with the x values from -5 to 5 (not squared). However, the error message I get is that x and y need to be the same dimension, but when I print out x and y list, they both have 11 elements in them. It seems like `get_qudratic_function` can't access the return value from the `get_x_squared()` function, even though I have defined it as `y_values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change y_values = get_x_squared() in function get_quadratic_function. So the code will look like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_x_squared():
    new_list = []  
    x_values = range(-5,6) 
    lista = list(x_values)
    for number in lista:
        new_number = number**2
        new_list.append(new_number)
    return new_list


def get_quadratic_function():
    y_values = get_x_squared() 
    x = list(range(-5,6))  
    y = y_values 
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel("x-axis")
    plt.ylabel("y-axis")
    plt.title("Quadratic function")
    plt.show()
print(get_quadratic_function())
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed I forgot the brackets.